# MySQL stored procedure - pass SELECT as a parameter

Tags: mysql, search, stored-procedures, reflection

Is it possible to pass prepared SELECT statement via Stored Procedure and execute it? Respectively - is it possible to dynamically create WHERE condition within SELECT statement in a stored MySQL procedure?

We want to enable variable searching over 40 columns. This means, there are 40*40 combinations, which we can also hardcode (and get some solution), but it seems to me too brute-force approach. Data set is be around thousands of records.

Comment: With free form searches like this, you will inevitably have expensive searches which have no indexes on them, potentially spelling larger problems if this tool you're building is widely utilized.  Take care.  A seemingly simple SELECT can bring a database down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is totally possible. Here is an example of what you are talking about that uses inserts and updates, not selects, but this is the basic form of what you need. The purpose of this procedure is to insert or update dynamically. The arguments for this query are the variable clauses for what either the insert or update statement would be. I hope this example helps to explain that what you wish to do is possible:

```
DROP procedure if exists `test`.`upsert_event`;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `test`.`upsert_event`(IN UPDATE_PARAM VARCHAR(10240), IN INSERT_PARAM VARCHAR(10240), IN REMOTE_ID_STRING VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

    DECLARE event_id_value INT(12) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE id_for_update INT(12) DEFAULT 0;

    # this temp table allows results to be returned and gets around a bug in our version of mysql
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS result_set(
        event_id int(12) DEFAULT 0,
        is_inserted tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0
    ) engine = memory;

    SELECT `events`.`id` INTO id_for_update FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`remote_id` = REMOTE_ID_STRING limit 1;

    # declare the variables that will be needed
    IF id_for_update != 0 THEN

        # build the update clause that you need
        SET @query_as_string = CONCAT('UPDATE `events` SET ', UPDATE_PARAM, ' WHERE `events`.`remote_id` = ', REMOTE_ID_STRING);

        PREPARE statement_1 FROM @query_as_string;
        EXECUTE statement_1;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement_1;

        INSERT INTO `result_set` (event_id, is_inserted) VALUES (id_for_update, 0);

    ELSE            
        #build the insert clause that you need
        SET @query_as_string = CONCAT('INSERT INTO `events` ', INSERT_PARAM);

        PREPARE statement_1 FROM @query_as_string;
        EXECUTE statement_1;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement_1;

        # set the id of the value update/inserted and return that as a reference
        SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO event_id_value;
        INSERT INTO `result_set` (event_id, is_inserted) VALUES (event_id_value, 1);

    END IF;

    SELECT * FROM `result_set` WHERE 1 LIMIT 1;
    DROP TABLE result_set;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I see you use sth. as prepared statements: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html Looks very useful. Thank you!